# How can I get a notification when a new child is added to the Firebase real-time database? (I want to use android services instead of FCM)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, service, notifications

This is what I have achieved yet! In my App, I have a notification turn on and notification turn off button. Turn on button start the service and set a listener to the database. Turn off button stop the service and remove database listener.

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
String CHANNEL_ID = "hostelmate_notification";

DatabaseReference databaseIssue;

ChildEventListener childEventListener;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Notifications activated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    databaseIssue = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("issues");
    childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            displayNotification();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    databaseIssue.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    databaseIssue.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Notifications deactivated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

public void displayNotification(){
    createNotificationChannel();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_active_white_24dp);
    builder.setContentTitle("Hostel Mate");
    builder.setContentText("New issue reported!");
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat =NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    int notificationId = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
}

private void createNotificationChannel(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        CharSequence name  = "Hostelmate notification";
        String description = "Hi";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);

        notificationChannel.setDescription(description);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
}
```

}

What is the issue with my approach?

I want to show notification only when a new child is added to the database. **But currently, notification is showing at the start of the service itself.**

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

ChildEventListeners trigger initially with *all* of the data at the chosen location.  Each child node that exists at that location will result in one call to `onChildAdded`.  There's no way to tell it to give you only "new" children.  If you want only certain items, based on current time, what you would have to do is make a query that only returns new items.  This probably involves including some timestamp in your child nodes, and querying for only the ones that are past the current time.

Instead, you could use Cloud Functions to trigger on new changes to the database, then in your function code, use Firebase Cloud Messaging to notify apps that are interested in the new children?